# Different quotes in html

Tags: html, css

When I`ve used this quotes «» in html text, they was different:

[image]
I have changed font generated in font-squirrel to same font from google cdn. On my PC quotes became normal in all browsers, on backend developer`s computer they still different(even after hard page reload in different browsers). 
What can we do for solving this?

Html example(header from picture):

```
<div class="block-title font22">
    Строительство ТРК «Лукьяновка» идет согласно плану.
</div>
```

Css:

```
.font22 {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    font-size: 22px;
}
.block-title {
    margin-top: 0.6em;
    max-height: 2.3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Google font:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100&subset=latin,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: Please post all relevant CSS code. Also try to use HTML entites: `&laquo;` and `&raquo;`

Comment: Might be related to used encoding on server

Comment: I just tried your html and css, and it looks different. However, I don't have any issue with quotes. Please tell what `DOCTYPE` you use, and maybe there's some other CSS and/or JavaScript that have influence on the header. [Here's the pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvoQEQ)

Comment: Yes, it works, but question is what I can do for computer where quotes still different after changing font

Answer (score 0):

If your document is using this charset:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Then you should be able to use (consistently across browsers) these marks “ would be `&ldquo;` & ” would be `&rdquo;`. Single quotes would be `&lsquo;` and `&rsquo;`.